# Windows 10 crashed so badly, can't even get inside login screen (AsIO.sys), restore not working

Tags: windows-10, bsod, login

I have Windows 10 in which on a very unlucky day I installed AI suite. Since then I get a BSOD with `AsIO.sys`. I tried System Restore, Reset this PC, and all sorts of crazy things Windows offers in their recovery console, but nothing worked so far. So I searched for that file `AsIo.sys` file from my Linux partition, logged in the recovery console, found it in `SysWOW64/drivers/AsIo.sys`, and eliminated it. Now the entire PC just freezes at the login prompt.

What are my options here? How can I reset the PC without reinstalling (preferably) so Windows 10 works again. Unfortunately as I cannot login into the Windows system, I cannot provide any logs. If anyone knows the log location, I am already logged into Linux, I can provide them.

Specs:

- **Motherboard** : Asus B350 plus AM4
- **CPU**: Ryzen 1700
- **OS**: Windows 10

Comment: Try editing the registry at `HKLM\System\ControlSet001\Services\AsIo` and disable it there, also find if any service's `DependOnService` contains `AsIo`. If there's none, locate an entry in `HKLM\System\ControlSet001\Services` that has a `ImagePath` pointing to that asio.sys, and disable that one (set `Start` to 4). Then try booting up.

Comment: @Vesper : Thank you for the prompt reply. Can you tell me how I can do this from command-line, as I cannot enter the system. Also, how to set the start-level to 4. I have deleted the hiberfile.sys btw...

Comment: Can you enter the W10 recovery/command line and launch a `regedit.exe` from there? If no, then use `reg.exe query  HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services /f '*asio.sys*' /s` it should show you the key. Then use the same `reg.exe` to delete and alter keys, check for its manual here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732643(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: @Vesper : No Asio.sys found in registry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE--->System-->Control_Set001...

Comment: So you've launched a regedit - nice, please check with "find" tool starting at `HKLM\System\ControlSet001\Services` for "asio", there should be some data referring to that driver. Otherwise, investigate the minidump with whatever tools available to find out which driver loads the asio.sys, find that and disable it too. Can't help much further, debugging driver load sequence remotely is very error prone, and I don't have much experience in this anyway.

Comment: @Vesper : Finally found the key when I logged into safe mode, but it didnt help, when I deleted the key and all its subfolders, then rebooted into normal mode, still the system freeze. Any idea how I can find what is causing the crash? Thanks.

Comment: Nice, but I only said disable, not delete. Also you should have checked the "DependOnService" entry on every other service that has "Start" entry as something other than 4 for the name of discovered key under "Services" - these check presence too. The type of that entry is `REG_MULTI_SZ`, meaning a multivalued string, to remove a dependency you should remove one entry from the multiline value in that entry. Also you might try turning safe boot on with `bcdedit /set {default} safeboot minimal` then booting in safe mode. With luck you'll be able to uninstall AI suite from there.

Comment: I experienced this same error, though I received it the first time I booted up my 1600x on the X370 chipset (I couldn't even install AI Suite since I had about 10 seconds before my computer BSODed).  From googling around, It appears that the new hardware switch over was causing drivers to fail, and throw this error.  I had to format my C:\ drive, and reinstall Windows 10 to fix it.  Not what you want to do, but that worked for me.  Luckily, I don't keep anything important on my C:\ so I didn't lose much. (http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/id-3326931/blue-screen-dead-asio-sys-error.html)

Comment: Thank you for this @vesper! Disabling the AsIO service saved my day.